# Iterating through a site's pages with python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, iteration

Is there a way to iterate through a page's archives where the format is

'http://base_url/page=#' - where # is 2-nth page number?

Ideally I'd like to  deploy my scraper on every successive page after 'base_url'

is the a function or for loop in python where the base_url would be iterated through like:

```
page = i in range(nth)
base_url ='http://base_url/page={}'
```

e.g. http://www.businessinsider.com/?page=3 vs. http://www.businessinsider.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just request each page like so:

```
# python 2
from urllib2 import urlopen
# python 3
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = "http://example.com/"

# request page 1 through 10
n = 10
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (i == 1):
        # handle first page
        response = urlopen(base_url)
    response = urlopen(base_url + "?page=%d" % i)

    data = response.read()
    # handle data here
```

EDIT: `urlopen()` returns an `HTTPResponse` or `addinfourl` object (depending on your Python version) - you need to call `.read()` on that to get the string of data. (I've updated my example code above, too).

Comment: When I run that with the business...url  I get x 10  - <addinfourl at 3060813416L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xb6709130>>

Comment: That's odd - in my testing, it returns an HTTPResponse (which you can treat as a file object). Can you post your code on a pastebin? (e.g. http://bpaste.net/)

Comment: Oh - `addinfourl` is the object returned by python 2 (I was using python 3, so I didn't realize). If you call `.read()` on the addinfourl objects, you'll get the data as strings.

Comment: would you happen to know how to filter returns - so the result set only returns with URLs with base_url+link_url??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, so when I scrape the urls I'm getting the desired plus some superfluous base_url returns - https://bpaste.net/show/1c592d438df6

Comment: If I recall correctly, `response.url` is the url, so you could just do `if response.url == base_url: continue` in the for loop.

Comment: Also, if you don't want the first page, just change `range(1, n+1)` to `range(2, n+1)` and remove the `if (i == 1)` statement.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do accomplish with regular expressions?

Comment: What do you want to do with regex? If you join http://webchat.subluminal.net/?channels=#programming, we might be able to help you there, as I'm not very good at regex :P